# How to check status process PID in c

Tags: c, windows

I wrote a small program in C.
But when i compile it on my pc it goes to "infinite loop" and my pc crashes.
program :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    label:;
    system("start sleep.exe ");
    goto label;
    return 0;
}
```

Solution required:

```
1) Check sleep.exe is runing or not in process task list of win7.
2) If not running then run sleep.exe.
3) Else goto label: for further checking.
```

Program may be something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    label:;
    IF process sleep.exe is runing then{goto label:}
    system("start sleep.exe ");
    goto label;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you prefer Windows or DOS? The answers are slightly different.

Comment: No sir.that i know. :) thank you.

Comment: In general one should prefer a loop (`do`/`while` looks good for this case) or functions to `goto` as they tend be easier to read. WHenever you use a `goto` you need to have a really good reason and the ability to explain why it is better than the recommended approaches to the people who are going to ask you why you chose `goto`.

Comment: This https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx might help you.

Comment: I agreed with you Sir about "do/while" suggestion but here my problem is that how to find sleep.exe PDI and complete my program with checking it continuously whether it is running or not .

Comment: If you elected to go with `system("sleep.exe")`, `system` would not return until `sleep.exe` completed, making the whole problem go away. I suspect this is not the route you wish to go because the main thread would block. A simple way around this would be to call `system("sleep.exe")` from another thread. Could you please expand on your end goal so we can suggest options better suited to your needs?

Comment: In modern Windows you can use the `CreateProcess` function to run sleep.exe. The PID is contained within the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure. Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx This does not work in DOS or ancient versions of Windows.

Comment: @ user4581301 7    yes sir,you mean this program cannot be solve this way,so what will be the alternative,I will prefer C only (please dont use DOS).

Comment: @user4581301 Sir, can we use fork() to complete these type of program.if yes then how possible we can use it.(by making two C file)one will check and other will execute. I just need PDI checking parameter in C for running other action.

Comment: `fork` is a [POSIX function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) not supported by Windows.

Comment: use `CreateProcessW` for exec some program. or, if it require elevation `ShellExecuteEx` with `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`. and use returned process handle for wait on it.